# Declined flag by moderator, so what is the correct one?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I flagged the following question as "low quality": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469724/i-need-suggestion-to-develop-a-game-on-canvas-or-and-engine

[image]

Moderator declined my flag.

1. What is the correct flag for this question?
2. I believe the question should be closed/removed. Unless I am missing something, why was it not closed by the moderator when they already inspected it?

Comment: Does too broad or primarily opinion based work?

Comment: "Primarily opinion based" applies, as it asks for opinion ("which is better"). "Too broad" could also apply (because there aren't enough details to determine which is more suitable for use).

Comment: In my experience, VLQ flags on questions frequently get declined by the community (rather than the mods), even on extremely incoherent and off-topic questions. The exception is questions in foreign languages or when no complete sentence is presented. I don't know why this is; VLQ flags on answers don't seem to have the same problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure why that flag was declined; the question was abysmally bad. I've deleted it.

You could also have flagged it for closure - "too broad" or "primarily opinion-based" both work here.

Comment: Can we have an "abysmally bad" flag?

Comment: @sm4 the VLQ flag is supposed to be that flag, as I understand it

Answer (score 3):

"Very low quality" is more for unintelligible gibberish. It's clear enough what is being asked on this question; it's just off-topic (recommendation/too broad/opinion-based).